# SweetAlert2 behavior with Jquery's keydown

Tags: jquery, sweetalert2

I use [sweet alert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) to customize messages. It works fine, but now I need to show an alert when a user presses the Enter or Tab key on an specific context in a page.

To trigger the alert i use Jquery's keydown method. My problem is that when I trigger the alert via the Enter key, it opens as if the user had already clicked on the confirm button.

I know that sweet alert, by default, interacts with the Enter key, but shoudn't it wait for a second Enter ? The first one triggers the alert and then the second interacts with the alert ?

As it is now, the enter key triggers the alert and confirms it at the same time. Is it possible to change something in order do open the alert and make it wait as usual ?

Here is a small [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CaioSantAnna/10yh8zc6/1/) with what i'm meationing. To see, alter between the enter and tab key. Thank you.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
    case 13:
    case 9:
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          Swal.fire(
            'Deleted!',
            'Your file has been deleted.',
            'success'
          )
        }
      })
    break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this with `e.preventDefault()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/eaq5x6zs/)**